# Extrude cylindrical shape with subdiv & bevel?

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel

I am stuck at modelling the enter button of a keyboard. The main shape is not a problem - rectangle with subdiv + loopcuts + mean bevel weight.

But how do I set this up the correct way to extrude a cylindrical shape in the middle while having one corner more round than the others (like for the other buttons where all edges are equally round & I could use the looptools to create the circle on the shape)?

I tried multiple ways & suggestions from googling but couldn't figure it out - any help would be very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would start from the divot shape itself, use either a QuadSphere or a UVsphere and scale it down almost completely on the Z-axis, then cut it in half, and extrude the outer edges to make the outside of the key.

Rather than making the cube and then forming the divot after the fact.
[image]

Result: [image]

Comment: Hey, thanks so much - that works & makes sense. How do you proceed after creating shape 1 and extruding to shape 2 (green seam to red seam - so the vertices are straight at the outer edges & the topology are nice)?

Answer (score 0):

In general you control curvature with holding loops:

[image]

It's generally agreed upon, that <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> creasing is inferior… The more you crease, the more subdivision levels (but that kind of defeats the point) you need on the creases for smooth curvature (unless you go for 100% crease, because then you don't want curvature):

[image]

Comment: I think he's talking about how to get the inset divot shape in the key itself.